# Playfair algorithm decryption problem with EOT

Tags: c++, algorithm, ifstream, eof

I'm trying to implement playfair algorithm with 16x16 matrix. Currently I have no problem encrypting and decrypting file if there is no pair of characters that would encrypt themselves into EOT character from ascii table.

Down here is my curent code for reading 2 characters:

```
    ifstream input_file(file);
    ofstream output_file("out_d.txt");

    if (input_file.is_open()) {
        char A, B;

        //get total number of characters in the file
        input_file.seekg(0, input_file.end);
        int length = input_file.tellg();
        input_file.seekg(0, input_file.beg);

        //while (input_file.get(A)) {
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < length / 2; cnt++) {
            input_file.get(A);
            //if there are 2 same characters in the pair
            if (A == input_file.peek()) {
                B = char(0);
            }
            //if there is a EOT charater ignore it and skip 1 character
            else if (input_file.peek() == char(3) && cnt != (length / 2) - 1) {
                input_file.ignore();
                B = char(3);
            }
            else {
                input_file.get(B);
            }
            //down here is the decryption section
            ...
        }
    }
```

The thing that I'm asking is if it is possible to skip or change position of file iterator, so I could decrypt the whole file even if there are multiple EOT characters.

Comment: Treat the encrypted file as binary data perhaps, though you will need to keep track of the size separately.  Convert back into text on decryption.

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem @rossum